# How to Disallow single decimal point(.)in input field with type number in angular js

Tags: angularjs, regex, ionic-framework

How can I show the error if the user write decimal point(.) in input field type number. I am using ng-pattern but it didn't validate when single full stop is entered.

For ex. If i entered number"9988587146." it didn't shows error or call ng-pattern function if i write two dots then it shows error .
for Ex "9988587146.."Everthing working fine all validationS except single dot (.) in input field
HTML

```
<input type="number" name="number" class="form-control" placeholder="Phone Number" ng-maxlength="10" ng-minlength="10" limit-to="10" step="0" ng-pattern="checkPattern()" ng-model="user.number"   required/>
```

My check Pattern function .

```
var isnum = /^[0-9]{10,10}$/.test($scope.user.number);
return isnum;
```

Comment: You need to use a `type="text"` if you plan to use a regex-based validation.

Comment: Wiktor Stribiżew But i want to show the android number  keyboard .

Comment: everthing working fine all validation except single dot (.) in input field

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two things you need to change in your code:

1. [`ngPattern`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngPattern) does not accept a function as its value. Only regex or a string that evaluates to a regex are valid values.
2. Like @Wiktor Stribiżew suggested in the comments, input with type `number` dose not work with [pattern validation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input#attr-pattern). Only `text`, `search`, `tel`, `url`, `email` or `password` will let you validate using a pattern. Since you try to validate a phone number anyway, I suggest you use type `tel`.

In your template, use:

```
<input type="tel" ng-pattern="checkPattern" name="number" class="form-control" placeholder="Phone Number" ng-maxlength="10" ng-minlength="10" limit-to="10" step="0" ng-model="user.number" required/>
```

And in the controller:

```
$scope.checkPattern = /^[0-9]{10,10}$/;
```